# Complex Scrolling Behaviour in Coordinator Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

[This is currently my layout (I am using a coordinator layout) i just want the horizontal recyclerView to scroll off the screen as the user Scrolls the vertical RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sURcp.png)

This is how my code looks like

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/feed_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

```
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1">
            
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/billabong"
                                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                        android:text="@string/instagram"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:textSize="33dp" />
            
                                </LinearLayout>
            
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="end">
            
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                                        android:id="@+id/notification_custom"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/heart" />
            
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/messenger" />
            
                                </LinearLayout>
            
                            </LinearLayout>
            
                        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            
            
                    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:id="@+id/feed_story_recycler"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:background="#000"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            
            
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/feed_recyler"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    >
                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            
            <!--    Footer -->
                <LinearLayout
            
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:paddingTop="9dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="9sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/home"
                            />
            
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/search"
                            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                            />
            
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/plus"
                            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                            />
            
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/reel"
                            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
                            />
            
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
                        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
                            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/goku2"
                            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circularImageView" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            
            
            
            
            
                </LinearLayout>
            
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).